# How to abort downloading a HTML image element from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am wrining a web app, which loads a bunch of images from a server. I've set up `.onload()` and `.onerror()` on each images, so I can monitor the "image download lifecycle". Even I've set up a `setTimeout()`, so I can detect timeout, too.

Upon timeout, I should abort the request. Browsers have limit on image request per same domain, and the stucked images should eat this limit up, pausing further image downloads.

I've tried `delete` the image element, remove from the DOM, setting new value to `.src` attribute, but neither helps. So, the question is: what is the official or non-official dirty way to abort http request of the `img` DOM element?

Comment: How would you prevent me from calling `wget /images/foo.jpg` from my shell script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929662/how-do-i-abort-image-img-load-requests-without-using-window-stop