# How to stop loading a image from loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

The problem I am facing is that I can't stop load an image in browser. I can stop it from appearing using

```
display:none;
```

but it still loads in the browser. I can't remove it as it's not in my control. Please help.

Comment: Please See this first: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[What-topics-can-I-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Explain your problem with some code snippet or example

Comment: Did you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929662/how-do-i-abort-image-img-load-requests-without-using-window-stop

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery .remove

```
$("#img_id").remove();
```

Or removeChild

```
var img = document.getElementById("img_id");
img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the image is not having any id and I have no control over it.