# How to prevent (inline style) background image from being loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, get, background-image

I have a div with an inline background style. I want to prevent this background image from loading as long as JS is enabled, to use less data, but let it load if JS is disabled. I also want to be able to get the URL of the image later on using jQuery.

I currently have this in a `<script>` element in my `<head>`, so that it works as quickly as possible (adapted from [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23594971/3217306)):

**JS**

```
function removeBackgroundImagesBeforeTheyLoad() {
      var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
      for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
          divs[i].style.removeProperty("background");
      }
}
// Fire the function every microsecond
var timer = setInterval(function() {
     removeBackgroundImagesBeforeTheyLoad();
}, 1);
// Stop firing the function after 3 secs
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
}, 3000);
```

This hides the image, but still allows it to load.

Comment: use CSS `div{background-image: none !important;}`. to tie to js, disable the stylesheet and un-disable it via JS.

Comment: `setInterval` looks **dangerous** to me..

Comment: @dandavis Could you do it without having an extra HTTP request for the extra stylesheet?

Comment: you could use a <style disabled> tag http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-style-element.html, and remove the _disabled_ via js.

Comment: @dandavis Good idea, but unfortunately, when JS is disabled, the `disabled` attribute doesn't seem to work

Comment: @BinaryFunt: yeah, its in the spec but i wasn't 100% sure it's followed. there's 5 other ways though. here's one: change my css above to `html.js div{backgr...` and then in script: `document.documentElement.className+=" js";`

Comment: @dandavis I found another way though: `var style = document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0];` then `style.innerHTML = "div { background-image: none !important; }";` **Update** Oh, just saw your comment

Comment: @BinaryFunt: that's another. anything will be better than iterating the DOM and modding many element styles...

Answer (score 0):

use **background=none**

```
function removeBackgroundImagesBeforeTheyLoad() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      divs[i].style.background=none;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, and moreover, throws an error that none is not defined

Comment: sorry my mistake: value is always assign as String. use this.
    divs[i].style.background="none";

Comment: It still doesn't work - it behaves the same way as `divs[i].style.removeProperty("background");`